# Decrypt smime.p7m

Tags: android, encryption, bouncycastle, smime

I am trying to decrypt an s/mime encrypted attachment (from Outlook/Exchange, smime.p7m) on Android using Bouncycastle.

I can decrypt/view the contents using p7mViewer on Windows.

The code, like ReadEncryptedMail.java from bc-java:

```
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(encryptedContent);
Session session = Session.getInstance(new Properties());
MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session, inputStream);    
SMIMEEnveloped smimeEnveloped = new SMIMEEnveloped(mimeMessage);
```

As a result i get java.io.IOException: DER length more than 4 bytes: 75  at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readLength(Unknown Source:53)

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of digging i found "how to generically parse a PKCS7 object" on the bouncycastle mailing list http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/how-to-generically-parse-a-PKCS7-object-td1467990.html

with the code i got a content type of ENVELOPEDDATA which lead me to trying a CMSEnvelopedDataParser who successfully parsed the content.

```
CMSEnvelopedDataParser cmsEnvelopedDataParser = new CMSEnvelopedDataParser(encryptedContent);
Collection recInfos = cmsEnvelopedDataParser.getRecipientInfos().getRecipients();
Iterator recipientIterator = recInfos.iterator();
if (recipientIterator.hasNext()) {
    RecipientInformation recipientInformation = (RecipientInformation) recipientIterator.next();
    byte[] contentBytes = recipientInformation.getContent(new JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient(privateKey));
    String content = new String(contentBytes);
}
```